# getHeight() of Non Inflated Custom View returns 0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-bitmap

What i want is to convert view to bitmap for which i need height and width of root view.
`getMeasuredHeight` and `getMeasuredWidth` is returning `0`, passed **View** is valid but does not return height and width,

*How can i get Valid Height and width without inflating Custom **View** class, using just java instance of Custom View Object.*

I'm using following snipet to get height and width of a view:

```
/**
     * Return the width of view.
     *
     * @param view The view.
     * @return the width of view
     */
    public static int getMeasuredWidth(final View view) {
        return measureView(view)[0];
    }

    /**
     * Return the height of view.
     *
     * @param view The view.
     * @return the height of view
     */
    public static int getMeasuredHeight(final View view) {
        return measureView(view)[1];
    }

    /**
     * Measure the view.
     *
     * @param view The view.
     * @return arr[0]: view's width, arr[1]: view's height
     */
    public static int[] measureView(final View view) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = view.getLayoutParams();
        if (lp == null) {
            lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
        }
        int widthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(0, 0, lp.width);
        int lpHeight = lp.height;
        int heightSpec;
        if (lpHeight > 0) {
            heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(lpHeight, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        } else {
            heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        }
        view.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
        return new int[]{view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight()};
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The dimension properties are not populated until the view is inflated and drawn. The only way you can get the properties are either hardcoding values, getting the dimensions from the `View.LayoutParams` if they are dimensioned other than `WRAP_CONTENT` or `MATCH_PARENT` or getting these properties after onCreate() in an Activity or onViewCreated() for a fragment.

If you want to convert a view to a Bitmap, you can draw that view in screen (It can be invisible for the user) and proceed from there.

Comment: I want to print my custom view as bitmap, but it is unnecessary to draw view on some layout each time, is there any way i can draw on temp layout and get my view height and width ?

Comment: Yea unfortunately you have to draw the view to print it/screenshot. you can draw it without the user noticing temporarily and removing it as soon as it is done. Does the view have any special things to it or is it just a Bitmap image? Because in that case you might the better off manipulating the bitmap alone instead of drawing it.

Comment: exactly can you show me how , or point out to any example that does it?

Comment: Remember if you hardcode dimensions (They could be relative to the screen dimensions too) you can do what you want.